# Pause / Restart AutoHotKey text playback

Tags: autohotkey

I have a simple AHK script that plays back text into an editor ( *see script below* ).

I want to be able to **Pause** / **Resume** the playback by pressing a sequence of keys.

I reviewed a few solutions here & at various AHK sites w/o success.

The script below should startup when I type Mike XXX ( and then press enter )  and should pause / restart when I use the Ctrl+Alt+P key sequence ...if I uncomment the Pause key sequence the script does not run at all ...any thoughts ?

**++++++++++
AHK Script
++++++++++**

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; ================ Define PAUSE key sequence ======================
;^!p::Pause  ; Press Ctrl+Alt+P to pause. Press it again to resume.
; =================================================================

BAS1 =  
(
This is line 1 of some text 
)
BAS2 =  
(
This is line 2 of some text 
)
BAS3 =  
(
This is line 3 of some text 
)

; ==================================================
; ====================== Start BAS definitions
; ================================================== 

::Mike XXX::
send, Mike XXX
 send, {enter 2}
SendDelay(BAS1)
 send, {enter 2}
SendDelay(BAS2)
 send, {enter 2}
SendDelay(BAS3)
 send, {enter 2}

return

; ==================================================
; ====================== End BAS definitions
; ================================================== 


SendDelay(text) {

  Loop, parse, text
  {
    Random, rdel, 5, 9
    Random, rdur, 6, 9
    SetKeyDelay, %rdel%, %rdur%
    Sendraw % A_LoopField
  }
}

; =================================== End Methods
```

Comment: Your first problem is the implicit Return that's part of your single line hotkey. From https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm: "...return serves to finish the hotkey. However, if a hotkey needs to execute only a single line, that line can be listed to the right of the double-colon. In other words, the return is implicit..." This ends the auto-execute section, preventing the rest of your script from running.

Are you wanting the script to pause in the middle of a line? I'm not sure how that would be done.

Comment: *"..Are you wanting the script to pause in the middle of a line.."* ...yes, that is the intent ...the idea is that I stop "pause" the sending of a text string and subsequently pick back up where I left off.